# How to simplify $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ka^{2k+1}}{(2k-1)(2k+1)!}$?

Tags: summation

I think that this sum can be simplified so that there's no factorial in the denominator and no exponential function in the numerator. But how can I do this? $a$ - is a constant. Could anybody show me step by step solution?
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^ka^{2k+1}}{(2k-1)(2k+1)!}$$

Comment: Do you know about generating functions? If you are interested in, you could get a clean expression for $n=\infty$

Comment: @AndreaMarino No, I don't. But for $n = \infty$ would be fine. I'm going even change the question for $n = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k a^{2k+1}}{(2k-1)(2k+1)!} = -a-a^2\sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^j a^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)(2j+3)!}=-a-a^2\int_{0}^{a}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}\,dx $$
equals
$$ -\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(a)+a\cos(a)+a^2\text{Si}(a)\right) $$
where $\text{Si}(a)$ is the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html). The partial sums of this series have no particular closed form I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks! But what if $n = \infty$ ? I've changed the question a bit. Now it's a sum of infinite series.

Comment: @VitaliiPaprotskyi: I have already replied - such a series is related to the non-elementary sine integral.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffc]{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k}a^{2k + 1} \over
\pars{2k - 1}\pars{2k + 1}!}} =
-a - \ic\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{2k + 1}a^{2k + 1} \over
\bracks{\pars{2k + 1} - 2}\pars{2k + 1}!}
\\[3mm] = &\
-a - \ic\sum_{k = 3}^{\infty}
{\ic^{k}a^{k} \over \pars{k - 2}k!}\,{1^{k} - \pars{-1}^{k} \over 2} =
-a + \Im\sum_{k = 3}^{\infty}
{\pars{\ic a}^{k} \over \pars{k - 2}k!}
\\[3mm] = &\
-a + \Im\sum_{k = 3}^{\infty}
{\pars{\ic a}^{k} \over k!}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k - 3}\,\dd t =
-a + \Im\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 3}^{\infty}
{\pars{\ic at}^{k} \over k!}\,{\dd t \over t^{3}}
\\[3mm] = &\
-a + \Im\int_{0}^{1}\pars{\expo{\ic at} - 1 - \ic at + {a^{2}t^{2} \over 2}}{\dd t \over t^{3}} =
-a + \int_{0}^{1}{\sin\pars{at} - at \over t^{3}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] = &\
\bbox[15px,#ffc,border:1px groove navy]{-\,{a^{2}\,\mrm{Si}\pars{a} + \sin\pars{a} + a\cos\pars{a} \over 2}}\
\pars{\mbox{after integrating repeatedly by parts}}
\end{align}

$\ds{\mrm{Si}}$ is the [Sine Integral Function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E9).